# Q: Update value in mysql table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SQL database with a table called 'Users' that includes: id, userName, password, firstName, lastName, and playerScore.

I'm trying to have my program update a player's score if they are logged in and win a game.  So from my code provided below if they are logged in I grab their username and their current score.  If they win I increment their score and update it, the problem I'm having is I'm not sure if I'm using the right statements to update it, I tried both (which have been commented out) UPDATE and INSERT to update my table for the new score but nothing changes in my database.

Any thoughts on how to proceed?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userName='$userName' and playerscore='$playerScore'";
$result = mysqli_query($mysql_handle, $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    $_SESSION['playerScore'] = $row['playerScore'];
    $_SESSION['valid_user'] = $row['userName'];
}

echo "<br>You Win!<br>"; 

$newScore = $_SESSION['playerScore']++;
//$sql = "INSERT INTO Users (playerScore) VALUES ('$newScore')";
//$sql = "UPDATE Users SET playerScore = $_SESSION['playerScore'] WHERE userName="$_SESSION['valid_user']";
```

Comment: sorry the UPDATE Users statement should be playerScore = '$newScore', don't know if that will make a difference.

Comment: There is a playerscore field name is different in query and in $_SESSION['playerScore'] = $row['playerScore']; and use the update statement.

Comment: update query >> $sql = "UPDATE Users SET playerScore = '".$_SESSION['playerScore']."' WHERE userName='$_SESSION[valid_user]'";

Comment: Use parameterized queries. Is the code in your question up to date; if not you should update it using the `edit` feature, not posting code in the comments. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some syntax errors in your update query. Try

```
$sql = "UPDATE Users SET playerScore = {$_SESSION['playerScore']} WHERE userName= '$newScore'";
```